# Rails 3 URL Helpers Not Working Correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Sigh - Rails 3 routing still seems to confound me. Here's the route.rb line -

```
match "/ghosts/:pid" => 'ghosts#update', :constraints => { :method => 'PUT' }
```

Here's the code in the view:

```
<%= form_tag (admin_ghosts_path(@pid), :method => :put) do |f| %>
```

and here's what gets rendered

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/ghosts.jbdlljhhxz" method="post">
```

but what should be rendered is

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/ghosts/jbdlljhhxz" method="post">
```

Suggestions? Also, is there a way to have the standard route:

```
resources :ghost, :only => [:index, :show, :update] do
  get :index
  get :show
  put :update
end
```

Use ":pid" instead of ":id" without doing the match like I have above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `admin_ghost_path(@pid)`, not `admin_ghosts_path(@pid)`.  Since you're calling a URL helper that doesn't have any regular arguments, the parameter that you are passing is being treated as a protocol argument value.

To see what the correct helper names for your routes are, run `rake routes` from the command prompt.

Comment: You get the check - it ended up being that i had to BOTH change from ghosts to ghost, and from using the match format, to using the standard 'member do' format -- btw, any idea how to stick the value in params[:pid] instead of params[:id]?